I want to add a 400 sq addition to my house and my existion may hace code vialation
I want to add a 400 sq addition to my house and my existion may hace code vialation, but am worried about preexisting code violations. If I had it upgraded and a building code inspector came out to inspect it, would he/she just inspect the new work or do they check the whole house for all building code violations?

Depends on (a) the type of violations (give us more details), (b) whether the previous work was permitted or not, (c) the jurisdiction and (d) the inspector's mood the day of the inspection. Too many things to guess.

It depends on how large the old violations are, how dangerous, how noticeable, on whether it's obvious they were violations at the time they were installed, and so on.  If you have a kitchen that was renovated with permits in 1980, then again without permits in 2000, and there are no GFCI outlets ... that's a code violation in 2000 but it's very hard to spot.  If you have a finished basement that was never permitted ... they may not look at all, or you may be royally screwed. I'm voting to close because this needs FAR more detail to be answerable.

If you have (as a typical instance) unpermitted work that is not on their plans, they very likely will notice it, and consequences can be major.  Better to try to get that sorted out with them before adding something else. Otherwise it may depend on the nature of the violation, but it's usually better to go ask them how to solve an issue you know (or suspect) is wrong than to hope they won't notice it.
It helps if you remember that their operating philosophy is that they are trying to ensure that your house is safe, since most of building code is concerned with not having people die because some thing that got into code because people died when it wasn't done isn't done. So if you are cooperating and attempting to get to the same goal-point, you look a lot better than if you are not.
This is, of course, easier if you are not personally the person who did work without a permit that required a permit when it was done. For other potential issues, we need to know more about the potential issues. i.e. permitted work only needs to have met the code in place when it was done - it does not need to be re-done every time code changes, until you do new work in that area; at which point the new work has to bring that part of the house up to current codes for the work being done.
And that has limits. If a part of the house has (typical issue with old houses) ceilings that are too low or stairs that are too steep for current rules, but those were in place before those rules came into force, remodelling that area will typically be grandfathered with respect to the ceiling height and stairs, unless the remodel involves rebuilding the stairs (and in some cases if those are the only size that fits, rebuilding them as they were is permitted.)
On the other hand, if an area was illegally converted from storage with low ceiling to bedroom and/or bathroom after the time that minimum ceiling heights were required, and the ceiling is too low, you'll probably be faced with correcting it, or reverting the use of the space. Likewise if non-compliant stairs were built after those rules came into force, even if they are the only stairs that fit.
